# Struts2 and hibernate

Tags: hibernate, jsp, struts2

I want to add persistance storage to my struts2 app. Where is the best place to start ?

I suppose I am looking for a good hibernate tutorial ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that you are using Struts has no impact on your choice for persistence technologies.  You can start with the hibernate documentation, and just search for Hibernate tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon how and in which application you want to use Hibernate with Struts2.There are some Struts2-Hibernate plugin available at Struts2 ceneteral plugin and can use them.

Optionaly you can create your persistance layer using hibernate can can always free to call from the Action classes/BO directly..

Answer (score 0):

[Hibernate in Action](http://www.manning.com/bauer/) is the best book to learn Hibernate quickly and easily.

Answer (score 0):

You can also refer to tutorials at Vaannila for Struts2 and hibernate integration.